# Set Text In TextInput react-native

Tags: react-native

Is there is any way to set again the text value in textinput of react-native ?
Like below , this is i'm doing :
i want to set my power translator text value in textinput.How can i do this ?

```
   <TextInput 
         style={{color:'black',width:width-60, borderColor: 'black'}}
         placeholder="Ask your Question ?"
         underlineColorAndroid='black'
         autoCapitalize="words"
         placeholderTextColor="black"
         keyboardType = "default"
         error = {this.state.errpwd}
         onBlur={() => this.setState({errpwd:""})}
         onChangeText={ (questionText) => this.setState({input: questionText}) }/>      

          <View style={styles.section}>
                <PowerTranslator style={styles.p} text={'user input: ' + this.state.input} />
            </View>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add value prop of to your TextInput

```
value={this.state.input}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: I'm using google translate API and for that i'm using npm power translator.Basically, my goal is that , when user enter some input on textinput then its automatically translate so for i'm do this type of thing where i translate my input by using power translator but now i want to set my translated text into textinput

Comment: You want the response from the power translator to reflect inside your text input?

Comment: That's a tricky task. You need to split your value inside text input after each space, select the last item in the array you got from split, send it to the translator server, wait for response,set the response as the last item of the array replacing the old one, and assign that value to the text input. This is a vague reply I know, but a direction. You need to make use of javascript methods and operators like split, spread etc to achieve this.